# How do I retrieve files stored in azure or in one drive with labview application?

Tags: azure, download, onedrive, auto-update, labview

I want to build a labview application starter which can check the main application version and eventually download and update the .exe file which is stored in my onedrive or even in somehow in azure.

I said azure because I think that there must be an option with it... But I can't get the correct keywords

Do anyone has some tip to share?

Answer (score 0):

The benefit of LabVIEW being a higher level application is that it gives you access to this little vi:
[image: System Exec VI implementation]

This is the System Exec VI which allows you to run general command line scripts from within LabVIEW. So if you can find a windows command to force the sync or a [batch file](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/oneDriveSync.bat) then you can interface with external programs.
The example Batch file there should work with OneDrive but with a little hunting around you should be able to find something to work with Azure.

P.S. Have a look at the 'Command Line Execution.vi' Example from LabVIEW to see more about how this vi works.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the reply.... I already use this vi, but I was looking for how to pratically access to a onedrive file and download it to a specific path... Now I'm digging into microsoft graph to get an api that does this job... But first i don't know if this is the correct path and second I'm not making any relevant progress...

Answer (score 0):

I wrote similar code that downloads and installs new releases from AWS S3. It is a real time-saver and worth the effort to get working.

I haven't interacted with OneDrive but from the documentation it looks a bit easier than AWS S3 because the Microsoft [accepts OAuth2 tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/getting-started/authentication) vs the more complex [AWS Signature Version 4](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4_signing.html). If you are using LabView, you'll need to use the HTTP client functions to interact with the remote service. I recommend starting with the [JKI HTTP REST API client toolkit](https://resources.jki.net/http-rest-api-client-for-labview). This toolkit works around a flaw in HTTPClient:OpenHandle function (it is globally blocking!) by maintaining a connection pool.

Microsoft's documentation looks pretty good; basically what you will want to do is open an HTTP session to the authorization endpoint, request an access token, close the HTTP session, open an HTTP session to the OneDrive endpoint, format the token into an `Authorization: bearer` header, add that header session, submit a [list file request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/drive_sharedwithme), find your file, submit a [download request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/driveitem_get_content), save the output to a file, close the http session.

Along the way you will need to parse the API's JSON responses. As NI's built-in JSON parser is rather inflexible, I recommend [JKI JSON](https://www.vipm.io/package/jki_lib_json_serialization/). Both of the JKI tools are most easily installed with VIPM, which is installed by default in recent editions of LabView.

Comment: Hi Robert, thanks for the support, one question:
the token you are talking about is the same one that i can get from this path?
https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/azure/storage/common/storage-auth-aad-app?tabs=dotnet

Comment: Yes, I believe so: "Instead, you can request an OAuth 2.0 access token from the Microsoft identity platform. Azure AD authenticates the security principal (a user, group, or service principal) running the application."